# Change query from NOT IN to NOt EXISTS

Tags: mysql, vba

im somewhat new to vba programming. I have this code i have written that is now becoming slow. I just recently moved from a backend table to an SQL table. the Query i am using, uses NOT IN. I have read in some places that using NOT EXISTS might speed things up. Here is my Code. i need to convert it to NOT EXISTS, but am unsure how:

```
SELECT BatchID
FROM TblBatchInfo
WHERE (IsNull([RSOutDateTime])=False) 
     AND (IsNull([HBDropDateTime])=False)
     AND (Format([BatchDateTime],"Short Date")=Format(Now(),"Short Date"))
     AND (IsNull(PSPassedOut=True) OR (PSPassedOut=""))
     AND LEN(LabelID)=9 
     AND [Area] <> 5
     AND [Area] <> 6
     AND [Area] <> 7
     AND (BatchID Not In (SELECT [BatchID]
                                          FROM [TblBatchInfo]
                                          WHERE (IsNull([RSOutDateTime]) = True)
                                           AND LEN(LabelID)=9
                                           AND [Area] <> 5 
                                           AND [Area] <> 6
                                           AND [Area] <> 7
                                           AND (Format([BatchDateTime], "Short Date") = Format(Now(), "Short Date"))))
GROUP BY BatchID
ORDER BY BatchID;
```

Comment: Everything in the WHERE clause of the NOT IN subselect is also in the main WHERE clause except for the reversal of the IsNull(RSOutDateTime).  Unless BatchIDs are repeated in this table, there should be no overlap.  I could be assuming wrong but you don't have a DISTINCT in the main SELECT clause which makes me suspect that you aren't expecting the same ID over and over.

Comment: To rephrase what I think @SteveBarron is saying: Just add the condition `RSOutDateTime is not null` and get rid of the whole subquery.

Comment: So this query is used to make a queue so to speak. it pulls all the batches and sees if the conditions are met and posts the batchID to a listbox to show that batchID is ready to go. So the BatchID is repeated throughout the table multiple times a day for each day.

Answer (score 0):

Use table aliases since in the subquery you'll be referencing both tables. Also you can do `NOT IN (5,6,7)` as opposed to multiple `<>`.

```
SELECT BatchID
FROM TblBatchInfo x
WHERE (IsNull([RSOutDateTime])=False) 
     AND (IsNull([HBDropDateTime])=False)
     AND (Format([BatchDateTime],"Short Date")=Format(Now(),"Short Date"))
     AND (IsNull(PSPassedOut=True) OR (PSPassedOut=""))
     AND LEN(LabelID)=9 
     AND [Area] NOT IN (5,6,7)
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 [BatchID]
                     FROM [TblBatchInfo] y
                     WHERE (IsNull([RSOutDateTime]) = True)
                         AND x.[BatchId] = y.BatchID
                         AND LEN(LabelID)=9
                         AND [Area] NOT IN (5,6,7) 
                         AND (Format([BatchDateTime], "Short Date") = Format(Now(), "Short Date"))
                    )
GROUP BY BatchID
ORDER BY BatchID;
```